# Cannot install any package of R

Tags: r, package, version

I was trying to reinstall a package beacause I have the following error:

```
A version of this package for your version of R might be available 
elsewhere,        
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/Radmin.html#Installing-packages
```

Here's the code:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("sf")
```

I tried to install different versions of R but I'm still having the same issue. And now I cannot install any package at all, because of the same reason

Anyone has experienced any related issue?

Session Info:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0 cli_3.2.0      jsonlite_1.8.0 rlang_1.0.2
```

Comment: This can happen when you have a too-old version of R, your repos cannot be used (or are empty?), you don't have the necessary compiling tools, or perhaps a number of other reasons. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()` into a [code block], then add the code you used to attempt to install it and then all of the output after it. This might be OS, R, or something else, so let's just start with that for now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What is the output from `getOption("repos")`?

Comment: CRAN
"https://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN"

Comment: If you try to go to that URL, it returns [HTTP 503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) (for me at least), suggesting that server is down, not routing correctly, or a myriad of other problems. Try setting your repo to another host, such as `options(repos="https://cran.r-project.org")` or using Posit's https://packagemanager.posit.co with `options(repos="https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest")`. They may not be "close" to you on the internet, but perhaps they'll get you up and running until ICESI is back.

Comment: Thank you so much! I change the host and works correctly

Comment: FYI, your question prompted me to update the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/3358272), a page with many suggestions on how to deal with errors about finding packages to install.